# action attached to selector in bootstrap table will not fire on page change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

This is an issue I have with Wenzhixin's Bootstrap table.

If I have a selector (ie a link) with an action attached (eg *on('click', fucntion() {...});* ) in any of the cells, that action won't fire when page is changed, sorting is applied search is performed.

Here's a short example: https://jsfiddle.net/L4h0gs4g/

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive"
data-show-toggle="true"
data-show-columns="true"
data-toggle="table"
data-sort-name="device"
data-sort-order="desc"
data-striped="true"
data-pagination="true"
data-search="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="device">Device</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="assettag">Asset Tag</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="serial">Serial No.</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">Service<br />History</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>RICOH SPC242SF PRINTER</td>
            <td>C013991</td>
            <td>T222PB01287</td>
            <td class="fleet_machine_actions">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="machine_actions" title="Service History">check</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>RICOH SPC242SF PRINTER</td>
            <td>C013991</td>
            <td>T222PB01287</td>
            <td class="fleet_machine_actions">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="machine_actions" title="Service History">check</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".machine_actions").on('click', function(e){
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
})
</script>
```

The link will trigger the alert box at first, but if you sort the table it will not trigger again. It's like jQuery cannot see that selector once the table's been changed / updated.

Is this a known bug or is there a workaround this at all?

Also posted on https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/2488

Comment: If, like me, you have items in your table that have events bound to them then it is recommended to delegate the events like so (to ensure the binding is preserved):
    $(document).on('click', '.class_selector', function(e){

Binding events like this on the other hand will *not* work for elements added dynamically (like after sorting the table):
    $('.class_selector').on('click', function(e) {

This is because the DOM changes and thus the binding will be broken, if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.machine_actions', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4h0gs4g/1/

BTW, you can use column option: `events` to do what you want: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options

https://jsfiddle.net/L4h0gs4g/2/

Comment: Cannot believe it was THAT simple! I've bee looking for a solution for a couple of days now... Thanks for your help!